# I can't use Point[] for loop

Tags: c#

I make a Point array assign some point, but I can't access them in for loop. What can help me, please?

```
Point[] _points;
private Point[] Points()
{
    Rectangle rc = ClientRectangle;
    Point[] _points=new Point[]
    {
        new Point{X=0,Y=ClientRectangle.Height/2}, 
        new Point{X=ClientRectangle.Width*22/277,Y=0}, 
        new Point{X=ClientRectangle.Width*68/277,Y=ClientRectangle.Height},
        new Point{X=ClientRectangle.Width*115/277,Y=0}, 
        new Point{X=ClientRectangle.Width*161/277,Y=ClientRectangle.Height},
        new Point{X=ClientRectangle.Width*206/277,Y=0}, 
        new Point{X=ClientRectangle.Width*254/277,Y=ClientRectangle.Height},
        new Point{X=ClientRectangle.Width,Y=ClientRectangle.Height/2} 
    };

    return _points;            
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    Graphics gfx = pe.Graphics;
    Pen kalem = new Pen(Color.Black);
    for (int i = 0; i < _points.Length; i++)
    {
        gfx.DrawLine(kalem,_points[i],_points[i].Y);  =======>>>ERROR HERE
    }            
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Comment: Pay more attention to what the error (that you should have included in your question) is telling you. You're overlooking something very obvious.

Comment: Do you call the `Points()` function before the `OnPaint()` function?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `_points[i].X` as the second argument?  Or is that just a typo?

Comment: error http://i.imgur.com/yKtKLr8.png

Comment: I had it backwards.  You need to pass in two points.  But drawing a line from a point to itself doesn't make sense.  Are you trying to draw a line from each point in your list to the next one?

Comment: I fixed it but this problem doent going it says cannot convert from int to System.Drawing.PointF

Comment: @AlgosuAresi Also for future reference you should really copy the compile error into your question versus adding a link to a screen print in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the variable(_points) in the function you override the scope of your attribute. The code you pasted never asigned anything to _points, which means that the array is empty.

Edit:
You cannot pass _point[i].Y since the method takes a PointF as an argument and _point[i].Y is an int.

Comment: This is a reasonable guess, and one of the things that could be wrong. It might not be the answer, though: it could just mean that the code that does assign to `_points` is missing from the question. The constructor might contain `_points = Points();`, for example.

Comment: accually I want to make custom controls not class

Comment: `Point` is [implicitly convertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.op_implicit(v=vs.110).aspx) to `PointF`.  So the OP can pass `Point` to `DrawLine`.

Comment: @k4rlsson Yes, I was just pointing out that he can pass a `Point` instead of a `PointF`. (No pun intended)

Comment: Just for further detail, the `DrawLine` method actually has an overload that takes `Point` instead of `PointF`.  Not sure why the compiler decided to use the `PointF` override in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
 gfx.DrawLine(kalem,_points[i],_points[i].Y)
```

you should pass _points[i].X here as with _points[i].Y i guess

Comment: I thought that too, but `DrawLine` takes two `PointF`s

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you actually want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _points.Length - 1; i++)
{
    gfx.DrawLine(kalem,_points[i],_points[i+1]); 
}
```

This will draw a line from the first point to the second then from the second to the thrid and so on.  If you need to close the shape then just add the following after the `for` loop.

```
// No point in drawing a closing line if there are not at least 3 points.
if(_points.Length > 2)
{
    gfx.DrawLine(kalem,_points[_points.Length - 1],_points[0]);
}
```